# how to use jquery plugin to view images in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, css, image, laravel

I am trying to use Image viewing plugin in Laravel but not able to do so.
when i used it without laravel it worked fine but when i am using it with Laravel its not working whats the reason and how to solve it??

plugin that i am using is Visual Light Box that i got from 
https://github.com/VisualLightbox/VisualLightBox

Also the Image cropping plugin is not working with laravel whereas working fine when used alone. I downloaded that from 
https://github.com/mkrmpotic/Simple-Image-Crop/tree/master/public

Thanks in advance for the Help...

Comment: do you get any error? maybe in the javascript console?

Comment: yes it says 
TypeError: (intermediate value).visualLightbox is not a function
/public/js/vlbdata.js
Line 5 : slideTime:4,startZoom:true,prefix:"pref2_"

Comment: All the CSS & JS files are Loaded into the page.
then why this error???
when I am using this without laravel Framework it works just fine No error nothing...

Comment: and while cropping the error is 
TypeError: $(...).simpleImageCrop is not a function